# How to do a result and row that will find the sql sum of two columns?

Tags: php, sql

```
Table 1               Table 2
_________________     ____________________
| ID| Name  |Age |    | ID| Cost  | Date  |
|---|-------|----|    |---|-------|-------|
| 1 | Kirk  | 33 |    | 1 |   10  |  9/10 |
| 2 | Lonzo | 55 |    | 1 |   20  |  7/8  |
| 3 | Dave  | 44 |    | 2 |   12  |  25/7 |
                      | 3 |   5   |  30/4 |
                      | 3 |   5   |  4/10 |
```

I want the result to be Kirk, who is 33, has a  total cost of 30 and total dates to 2
etc.. (btw they enter their names and all this comes up)

**The sql statement would be like this?**

```
$sql= "SELECT Table1.Name, Table1.ID, Table2.ID, Table1.Age, SUM(Table2.Cost), SUM(Table2.Date)
AS count from Table1, Table2
WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID and Table1.Name = (my example here)"
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$Cost = 0;
$Date= 0;
$rec = $result->fetch_assoc();
$Date= $rec{'count'};
$Cost= $rec{'count'};
$Age = $rec{'Age'}
```

echo "$Name, who is $Age years old a total cost of $Cost and $Date total dates";

**Im getting errors, saying my variables are undifined**
so how would I put them into variables?

**EDIT fixed**
instead of using the sql to find it, i used result from a while loop that kept adding one to another variable (to count the date). The cost is able to do in both sql(sum) and result.

Comment: `SUM(Table2.Date)` is not going to work. Then again what do you expect it to be?

Comment: I think you need to research `GROUP BY`

Comment: double check your `$sql` variable you did not even include the quotations `$sql = "sql statement here";`

Comment: So what statement would you use for the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using the sql to find it, i used result from a while loop that kept adding one to another variable (to count the date). The cost is able to do in both sql(sum) and result.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a group clause. I also put that in a subquery and used  an `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT Id, Name, Age, Cost, Dates
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT Id i, SUM(Cost) Cost,
  COUNT(Date) Dates 
  from Table2 
  GROUP BY Id) t
ON i=Id
WHERE Name = 'Kirk'
```

You should also change one of the php statements to

```
$Cost= $rec{'Cost'};
```

Comment: Also it is coming up with an error, this---->"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean...Stack trace: #0 {main}" This is for my $rec = $result->fetch_assoc();

Answer (score 0):

Just use join..

```
SELECT table2.date ,SUM(cost) AS tatol FROM table1 
JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
WHERE table1.id = 1
```